# C++ const struct &variable yields missing tag name

Tags: c++, struct, constants

Trying to initialize and set things up for a class as follows:

```
class Accel
{
public:
    Accel(const struct &F, const struct &m, const struct &M, const struct &I);

    etc...
}
```

I get "'struct': missing tag name" when I try to compile. I'm using someone (who I trust) else's coding "conventions", which is where the "const struct &..." comes from, but if someone knows a better way to do that, then let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`struct` is a keyword in C++; it cannot be used as a type name. Use something else instead:

```
class Dennis;
struct Janet;  // "struct" is pretty much identical to "class"

class Accel
{ 
public:
    Accel(const Dennis & F, const Dennis & m, const Janet & j) { /* ... */ }
    // ...
};
```

(Type naming in C++ is different from that in other languages, such as C. In C++ you say, `class Dennis; Dennis x;`, while in C you would have to say `struct Janet; struct Janet y;`, or use a typedef to make a typename that you can use without saying "struct".)

Comment: I have declared F, m, M, and I as structs of doubles (elsewhere). So if I use "double" in place of "struct" what will happen? For example, F contains three doubles - Fx, Fy, Fz.

Comment: @user1187621: There's no such thing as a "struct of doubles". Your actual type *will* have a proper name. Look for it, and use it. There are no anonymous structs in C++.

Comment: @user1187621, If I understand you correctly (`struct F {double Fx; double Fy; double Fz;};`), you need `const F &` in your declaration and `const F &parameterName` in your definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
const struct &F
```

What is the type of `F` here?  `struct` is not a type (nor do you need that qualifier in C++).  I believe you want something along the lines of:

```
struct Foo {};

class Accel
{
public:
    Accel(const Foo &f, ...);
};
```

C requires the `struct` keyword when declaring a variable of a `struct` type, but even then you cannot simply omit the type name.  Usually (in C) you would `typedef` the `struct` to avoid typing `struct` everywhere.

```
typedef struct {
    char *whatever;
} my_struct;

int main() {
    my_struct s;
}
```